# cryptography.fernet.invalidtoken airflow error

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

Unfortunately I deleted airflow on eks which is deployed via helm chart. Connections and variables are encrypted with fernet key in the databse.when I deployed new airflow via helm again, Everything seems to be running up and fine. Only issue is I see the connections are not able to read by airflow and it is showing the below error in connections tab
`cryptography.fernet.invalidtoken airflow`

I also checked the fernet key in secrets and as well by doing exec into webserver pod. Both are same.

Can someone help me please.